# How to handle "The size of input should not exceed 64K" exception in emailcomposetask?

Tags: windows-phone-7, email, size, windows-phone-7.1, task

`EmailComposeTask` on WP7 is very limited as I cant send attachments using my code. I am trying to send text as body in the `emailcomposetask` and it is throwing this `The size of input should not exceed 64K` exception. Note that my text is `42.9 Kb` in size according to `Notepad`. How to handle this exception? Is there any solution/alternative/workaround this?

I also want to know what `encoding` the emailcomposetask follows for its content so that I oculd check the equivalent size of my content in that particular encoding? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I did, I converted the text to `Unicode` and trimmed the last 63K buffer of the text which I want to send. Works perfectly for my situation. Thanks for your help guys. :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are not counting with the email overhead of the message header, encoding the body, etc.

Per example, if the message body is encoded in Base64, it will get at least 1/3 larger than the original non-encoded message!

I don't think there is an ideal solution for this, though I'd try to keep the message below the 40k of text.

Comment: so what size should I keep in order to prevent this? till now I was keeping it at 60K. Even if i reduce the limit to 40K or lesser and the decoded text is more than 64K this excpetion will again pop up right?

Comment: True... So just play it safe, and use a modest value, something along the lines of 35k or 40k of text

Comment: but my text is dynamic. It will change with user's usage. Then what?

Comment: Use an other variant. Send it by http.

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) coding overhead. Try to compress your text.

Comment: so what size should I keep in order to prevent this? till now I was keeping it at 60K. Even if i reduce the limit to 40K or lesser and the decoded text is more than 64K this excpetion will again pop up right?